# Referencing resources in other resource groups

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

In Azure, I'm deploying infrastructure to Resource Group 02 (rg02) using Terraform. I have a VNet (nvn01) and subnet (subnet-000) in Resource Group 01 (rg01), and need to reference this in a resource in `main.tf`.

I have tried three ways:

#### Method 1

Providing the subnet id as a variable. The subnet id has been copied and pasted from [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com). `init` doesn't produce any error, however, `plan` generates:

```
1 error(s) occurred:

* module.app_gateway.azurerm_application_gateway.network: 1 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_application_gateway.network: Error Creating/Updating ApplicationGateway "appgw01" (Resource Group "rg02"): network.ApplicationGatewaysClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="NotFound" Message="Resource /subscriptions/mySubscriptionGuid/resourceGroups/RG01/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/NVN01 not found." Details=[]
```

.tfvars contains the line:

```
subnet_id = "/subscriptions/mySubscriptionGuid/resourceGroups/rg01/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/nvn01/subnets/subnet-000"
```

I wonder if there is an issue with CaSe as the RG and VNet come out in upper case. I know Azure can be CaSe SeNsItIvE at times.

---

#### Method 2

There is a [bug #2016](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/2016) with this method, fixed in the unreleased version 1.17.0.
Using `data{}`, I reference the subnet thus:

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "shared" {
  name                      = "$(var.shared_virtual_network_subnet_name)"   
  virtual_network_name      = "$(var.shared_virtual_network_name)"
  resource_group_name       = "$(var.shared_resource_group_name)"
}
```

and in my resource, call it `subnet_id = "${data.azurerm_subnet.shared.id}"`

This errors at the `init` stage, where the aforementioned bug is apparent. I've tried to tell TF to use 1.17.0 by setting `version = "1.17.0"` in the `provider{}` declaration, but it's ignored and I end up with `1.16.0`.

---

#### Method 3

I have also tried Method 2, but instead of using `azurerm_subnet`; opted for `azurerm_virtual_network` and called it using:

```
subnet_id = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.shared.id}/subnets/${var.shared_virtual_network_subnet_name}"
```

However the error is the same as with Method 2 and I note the resource group is in the wrong place. I hope 1.17.0 fixes both bugs.

In ARM templates, I recall one had to use `ResourceId('subnetId')` in this scenario, so I wonder if there is a similar function in TF. Maybe I have to prefix the subnet id path?

Anyway, as the Azure provider examples are thin on the ground, to say the least, if anyone has any pointers, I'd be grateful if you'd share, in getting 1.17.0 downloaded without having to build it myself or fixing the subnet id.

TIA.

Comment: As i figured out by now, this is actually currently not possible in Microsoft Azure. Since the Subnet and VNET Resource Group can't be splitted

Comment: I'm not trying to split the VNet from its subnet.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the plugins folder in your .terraform folder and rerunning? That should force the provider to be downloaded and get the udpate.